# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple HTML5 interactive video player in which a user can play different video using buttons on click.

I have added a button goback which allow a user to go back to the previously played video.

Here  is html

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" canplay id="video-block">                    
                <div id="video-container">
                        <video id="videoplayer" playsinline autoplay>
                            <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                        <div id="interactive-layers">
                                <!-- <div class="go_back">Go back</div> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="video-controls">
                        <div id="seek-bar-container">
                        <div id="seek-bar">
                            <div id="current-time">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="pause-play-button">
                        <span id="play">play</span>
                        <span id="pause">pause</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my js

```
var movies = null;
var flowchart = null;
var connections = null;
var videohistory = [];


$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
        movies = data.movies;
        $.getJSON('datasaved/settings2.json', function (data) {
            flowchart = data.movies;
            connections = data.connections;

            for (var c = 0; c < connections.length; c++) {
                connections[c].buttonid = String(connections[c].buttonid).split("moviebuttons")[1];
                connections[c].movieid = String(connections[c].movieid).split("movieblock")[1];
            }

            for (var j = 0; j < movies.length; j++) {
                for (var i = 0; i < flowchart.length; i++) {
                    if (flowchart[i].checkbox == true && flowchart[i].movieid == movies[j].movieid) {
                        playVideo(movies[j], flowchart[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        setInterval(updateTimeline, 40);
    })

    $("#interactive-layers").on("click", ".video-btns", buttonLinkClicked);
    $('#interactive-layers').on('click', ".go_back", function () {
        playVideo(videohistory[videohistory.length - 2], true);

    });

    video = $("#video-container").find('video');
    video[0].addEventListener("timeupdate", onUpdateTime);
    video[0].addEventListener("canplaythrough", videoReady);
    video[0].addEventListener("pause", onPause);
    video[0].addEventListener("play", onPlay);
    video[0].addEventListener("ended", onEnded);
    video[0].addEventListener("timeupdate", onUpdateTime);
})

function buttonLinkClicked(e) {

    var mov = null;
    var flo = null;

    for (var j = 0; j < movies.length; j++) {
        if ($(e.target).attr("targetmovieid") == movies[j].movieid) {
            mov = movies[j];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < flowchart.length; i++) {
        if (flowchart[i].movieid == $(e.target).attr("targetmovieid")) {
            flo = flowchart[i];
        }
    }

    if (mov == null || flo == null) {
        $(this).attr('buttonid');
        var getButon = $(this).attr('buttonid');

        switch (getButon) {
            case "5":

                window.open('https://www.meed.com/', '_blank').focus();

                break;

            case "6":

                window.open('https://buy.meed.com/', '_blank').focus();

                break;
            case "7":

                window.open('https://www.meedprojects.com/projects-platform/bespoke-services', '_blank').focus();

                break;

            case "60":

                window.open('https://premium.meedprojects.com/Login', '_blank').focus();

                break;
        }

    } else {

        playVideo(mov, flo);
    }

}

function updateTimeline() {
    if ($("#videoplayer")[0].duration) {
        $(".video-btns").each(function () {
            if ($("#videoplayer")[0].currentTime >= parseFloat($(this).attr("starttime")) && $("#videoplayer")[0].currentTime < parseFloat($(this).attr("endtime"))) {
                $(this).addClass("show");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("show");
            }
        });
    }
}



function addGoBack() {
    var goback = $(" <div class='go_back'>Go back</div>");
    $("#interactive-layers").append(goback);
}

function playVideo(movie, flowchartvideo, back) {

    var movieHistory = Object.values(movie);

    $("#interactive-layers").html("");
    addGoBack();

    if (back == true) {

        videohistory.pop();

    } else {

        videohistory.push(movieHistory);
        console.log(videohistory);
    }

    if (videohistory.length == 1) {
        $(".go_back").addClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $(".go_back").removeClass('hidden');
    }


    var buttons = movie.buttons;

    for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {

        for (var c = 0; c < connections.length; c++) {
            if (connections[c].buttonid == buttons[b].buttonid) {
                buttons[b].targetmovieid = connections[c].movieid;
            }
        }
    }

    $("#videoplayer").attr("src", movie.movie_url);
    $("#videoplayer")[0].muted = false;


    //  alert(buttons.length);
    for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {
        var buttonid = buttons[b].buttonid;
        var label = buttons[b].label;
        var starttime = buttons[b].start_time;
        var endtime = buttons[b].end_time;

        var videobtns = $("<div buttonid='" + buttonid + "'  class='video-btns' targetmovieid='" + buttons[b].targetmovieid + "' starttime='" + starttime + "' endtime='" + endtime + "'><span class='label'>" + label + "</span></div>")
        var top, left, width, height;
        top = buttons[b].top
        left = buttons[b].left
        width = buttons[b].width
        height = buttons[b].height;

        $("#interactive-layers").append(videobtns);
        videobtns.css({
            top: top,
            left: left,
            width: width,
            height: height
        })
    }
}
```

When the user plays the second video the goback button appear, and the user can click it and play the previous movie

Now when I click goback I get the following error

main.js:156 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

**UPDATE**

> Here is live demo : [live demo](https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/editor/preview.html)

What am I doing wrong? or can some one provide a simple method for this?

Comment: You have no variable `connections` anywhere, what is `connections.length`?

Comment: Which line is line 156?

Comment: `for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++)`

Comment: @Barmar I dint add connections because there is no problem with it , i just want to play the previous played video am not sure if am doing the right way

Comment: @Barmar  have added all the code am using for my player and live demo

Comment: The error means that `movie.buttons` is undefined. Check the value of `movie`.

Comment: @Barmar on console the movie.buttons before clicking goback button its displaying the value , just after clicking  goback shows this eror, you can check it on live demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered way to fast, after checking your working code, I suggest you take a closer look at the line...

```
var movieHistory = Object.values(movie);
```

It does not appear to do what you want it to. (clone the movie object).
Just change it to

```
var movieHistory = movie;
```

It works for me in Chrome Dev console...

Comment: I will try here is live demo `https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/editor/preview.html`  check it

Comment: I have all the code I am using check the updated question, this line is to convert object to array , check the  code

Comment: yes, it converts the object to an array, but that gives you the problem next time you call the function. It expects an object, but now it gets an array.

Comment: for fun, try changing "var movieHistory = Object.values(movie);" to "var movieHistory = movie"

Comment: what does that line suppose to do?

Comment: You want to save the previously shown video in an array to be able to skip back to it, but just because you want an object in the array is no reason to convert it into one. just put the original movie object in the history array, it will work.

Comment: @user9964622 It should have been obvious if you did `console.log(videohistory)`. It doesn't contain an array of objects.